# is it possible to get the total width of a jquery tab?

Tags: jquery

is it possible to get the width of the different tabs with different lengths of text inside?

for instance

| tab 1 | motion sickness | computer |

the tab 1 = 20px

motion sickness tab  = 100px

computer tab = 60px

something like that

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly how much of the width you want. You can use [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) to include margins or [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get the basic width.

Where tab1 and motionSickness are element id's:

```
var width = $('#tab1').width();
var outerWidth = $('#motionSickness').outerWidth();
var totalWidth = $('#tab1').width() + $('#motionSickness').width();
```

ADDITION:

If you want to loop through them, you can to it with the same id's as above like so:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('#tab1, #motionSickness').each(function(){
   totalWidth += $(this).width();
});
```

You can also give all those tab elements a class and then change `$('#tab1, #motionSickness')` to `$('.tab')`. Also, may help to brush up on the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) for the correct selectors and methods and such.

Comment: hi, how would you run through each tab like in a loop?